# Flash Builder Profiler Memory Usage

Tags: air, profiling, flash-builder, flex-mobile

The Flash Builder (4.6) profiler shows a current memory usage of about 24000k (so 24MB if I'm not mistaken) for my app, which simply cannot be.
The live object view, however, shows for example that the object with the highest memory consumption, 80 live instances, consumes 119000bytes, or 10% of the overall memory consumption.

That doesn't really sum up to 24MB now, does it? Can someone explain to me how the profiler calculates the memory consumption?

Comment: This may be a better question over at the Adobe forums.  I am not sure if there is any public information about the internals of the Flash Builder Profiler

Comment: Fiar enough. I just figured that someone else around here must have stumbled across this weird behavior as the Flash Builder help pages clearly state that "The value for Current Memory is the same as the sum of the totals in the Live Objects view’s Memory column, assuming that all filters are disabled.", which they are not, though. I mean adding a button with a custom skin class that only uses a FXG adds one MB (in to the graph not the actual live object), I don't think so. ;) But good idea with the Adobe forums, hopefully there's still people around...

Comment: I'm not a profiler expert, but are you sure that all filters are disabled?  I think, by default, a lot of the Flex/Flash classes are not listed there.  If they are listed, it is sometimes hard to find your own classes.

Comment: Damn those bloody filters. I thought I disabled all of them. But yes, `flash.display` was still enabled. Now it adds up. Please post your comment as a formal answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Profiler, there are filters in place by default and that includes hiding certain Flash and Flex classes from the display.  Be sure that you've removed all filters.

As stated in the comments on the main question, in this case you had not removed the filter for flash.display; meaning that those classes were not displayed in your class list, yet their memory usage were still calculated in the memory usage.